# How to properly install new completions in zsh?

Tags: zsh, zshrc, tab-completion

The whole issue is discussed [here](https://github.com/DannyBen/alf/issues/39) and [here](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/issues/2489). Since no one involved in those discussions was 100% sure about the issue, I'm asking for help here. (For the sake of completeness, I'll start from the beginning.)

Let's say we have two scripts (sourced in `~/.zshrc`) that set up some completion logic for ZSH. Now based on what I learned, at some point in the script you need to call `compinit` and `bashcompinit` like this (copied from NVM completion script)

```sh
if [[ -n ${ZSH_VERSION-} ]]; then
  autoload -U +X compinit && if [[ ${ZSH_DISABLE_COMPFIX-} = true ]]; then
    compinit -u
  else
    compinit
  fi
  autoload -U +X bashcompinit && bashcompinit
fi
```

Apparently, according to ZSH manual, `bashcompinit` must be called after `compinit`, (not sure if it's relevant). Now the problem is, the moment the second script calls `compinit`, the logic coming from the first script is gone (i.e. no completion from the first script is available). A simple snippet to reproduce this is (copied from [here](https://github.com/DannyBen/alf/issues/39)):

```sh
complete -W "hello world" one
one <tab>   # to see autocomplete working
compinit 
one <tab>   # to see autocomplete NOT working
```

Someone proposed ([here](https://github.com/DannyBen/alf/issues/39)) something like below to solve the issue (by checking if `compinit` is already called before calling it):

```sh
if [[ -n ${ZSH_VERSION-} ]]; then
  if ! command -v compinit > /dev/null; then
    autoload -U +X compinit && if [[ ${ZSH_DISABLE_COMPFIX-} = true ]]; then
      compinit -u
    else
      compinit
    fi
  fi
  autoload -U +X bashcompinit && bashcompinit
fi
```

Another idea could be to call `compinit` and `bashcompinit` not in the custom completion script, but in `~/.zshrc` (which hurts the automated installation process for tools like NVM).

I'd like to know what is the correct way to set up completion in general (or specifically with respect to calling `compinit`).

Thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### Installing native Zsh completions

> Let's say we have two scripts (sourced in `~/.zshrc`) that set up some completion logic for ZSH. Now based on what I learned, at some point in the script you need to call `compinit` and `bashcompinit`

Nope, that's not what your script should be doing. Not your script, but the *user* should call `compinit` (in their `.zshrc` file) to enable [Zsh's more advanced completion system](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html).
Additionally, it should be called *only once* for each shell instance.

<sub>A more basic, Bash-like completion system is enabled by default in Zsh, but it's [pretty much deprecated](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Completion-Using-compctl.html#Completion-Using-compctl). *Don’t* bother with it; the vast majority of your users have `compinit` in their dotfiles, which provides a much better user exerience, even though it's not enabled by default. Yes, Zsh ships with poor, archaic defaults in the name of backwards compatibility. Nearly all its newer features are opt-in, unfortunately.</sub>

*This* is the proper way to add native completion functions to Zsh:

1. Check if you can write to the directory `/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions`, as this is in every Zsh user's `$fpath` by default.

   - If you can, then create symlinks to each of your completion functions in this directory.
   - If you cannot, then tell the user to add the following to their `.zshrc` file:

     ```
     fpath=(
         /path/to/dir/containing/your/completion/functions 
         $fpath
     )
     ```
2. Tell the user to make sure the following gets called from their `.zshrc` file (or scripts that they `source` from there), *after* setting the `$fpath`, in the order given:

   ```bash
   autoload -Uz compinit
   compinit
   ```

   <sub>Many Zsh frameworks & plugin managers include a call to `compinit` on startup. Calling `compinit` more than once increases startup time significantly and erases completion functions added programmatically. You might want to make your users aware of this, to save yourself needless bug reports.</sub>

`compinit` will then automatically pick up your completion functions from the user’s `$fpath`.

### Installing Bash completions in Zsh

> Apparently, according to ZSH manual, `bashcompinit` must be called after `compinit`, (not sure if it's relevant).

Yes, it's relevant, but no, not in the way you think it is. Among other things, `bashcompinit` defines the function `complete`, which emulates Bash’s `complete` builtin and can be used to add Bash completions to Zsh. Like `compinit`, `bashcompinit` is meant to be called only once per shell.

If your package supplies Bash completions only, then you can do the following to install them in Zsh:

1. Tell the user to make sure that the following get called from their Zsh dotfiles, in the order given:

   ```
   autoload -Uz compinit bashcompinit
   compinit
   bashcompinit
   ```
2. Tell them to then follow the same instructions as for installing your completions in Bash.

*However,* Zsh's completion is much richer and more powerful than Bash’s. Whenever possible, I would recommend supplying a native Zsh completion function. Here's a good guide on [how to write Zsh completion functions](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-completions/blob/master/zsh-completions-howto.org).

Comment: thank you! I really need some guide to compinit, I admit I have just been copy-pasting without much thought into it. Yours was a great primer!