# Is there a way to count the number of times a command is called during zsh startup?

Tags: autocomplete, zsh

I was reading through the answer to a related question on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67161186/) and the answer mentioned:

> Nope, that's not what your script should be doing. Not your script, but the user should call `compinit` in their `.zshrc` file to enable Zsh's completion system. Additionally, it should be called only once for each shell instance.

I'm curious if it is possible to count the number of times that `compinit` or `bashcompinit` is being called during zsh startup?

Thanks.

Comment: If you look at _man zshcontrib_, you will find a `add-zsh-hook` defined. Using this, you write a hook  for i.e. compinit, and inside the hook you increment a counter. The problem is where to place the `add-zsh-hook` definition. You want to find **all** invocations during  zsh-startup. This means that you would have to define the hook at the beginning of `/etc/zshenv`, to be on the safe side.  Since you perhaps don't have permission to modify this file, the second-best choice would be your own `.zshenv`, which is  in your home directory (or whereever  `ZDOTDIR` points to).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the zprof module makes this pretty easy: add `zmodload zsh/zprof` to the top of `~/.zshenv` and run `zprof` once the shell starts up (maybe pipe to `grep compinit` too). It will list all the functions that were called since the module was loaded, with the number of calls and time they took. See its section in [`zshmodules(1)`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#The-zsh_002fzprof-Module) for more details.

`~/.zshenv` will be read immediately after `/etc/zshenv`, and before anything else. There shouldn't be any `compinit` calls in `/etc/zshenv`, since it's also read for non-interactive invocations of `zsh` like `zsh -c ...`.